# parse string array to get integer value in java

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

I have an string like"2=33=file". I can get the first number from the string by

```
char[] cArray = new char[4];
int nValue = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cArray[0]));
```

How can i get the value "33" from the string .Also if i have in String like "2=3=file" also i want to get the value "3".    Sorry if this is a very simple question to ask or may be this being very specific case.

Comment: Did you do any research? There are probably a hundred questions on this topic here on SO.

Comment: I got the "lastIndexOf" but couldnt distinguish 1-digit & 2-digit value to extract from the string

Comment: search for regex in java or String.split function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
String str = "2=33=file";
String[] arr = str.split("=");
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);       // value - 2
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);       // value - 33
String s = arr[2];                         // value - "file"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my example will help you too.

```
public class Solution{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = new String("beard=true;age=20;");
    System.out.println(parse(s, "beard"));
    System.out.println(parse(s, "age"));
}

static String parse(String where, String what){
    String s;
    if(!where.contains(what)) return null;
    int i = where.indexOf(what) + what.length() + 1;
    where = where.substring(i);
    i = where.indexOf(";");
    s = where.substring(0, i);
    return s;
}
```

}